# Switching to tabs to the right or left of the current tab in Notepad++

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, notepad++, tabs

How can I switch to the document to the left or right of the current document in Notepad++?

For example, if I have documents `A`, `B`, and `C` open, and I'm currently editing `B`, I would like a shortcut to be able to:

1. switch to document `A`, like. . . (<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>LeftArrow</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Pageup</kbd>)

OR

2. switch to document `C`, like. . . (<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>RightArrow</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>PageDown</kbd>).

All I've found is a way to switch to next or previous documents based on the "history" of when the document was last opened, for example:

(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd>)

The examples I have found are useful, but not what I want.

Is what I am asking for possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I switch tabs in Notepad++ via Ctrl+PgUp/Down?](http://superuser.com/questions/299399/how-can-i-switch-tabs-in-notepad-via-ctrlpgup-down)

Comment: This has been default behaviour in Notepad++ since 6.4.5 (2013-08-09 https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v6.4.5.html). There's nothing in the patch notes, but I just downloaded a whole bunch of old versions and this is the first one that displays this behaviour out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 79):

### Update

The functionality is included by default in Notepad++ v6.4.5 and later.  6.4.5 was released August 9th 2013.  Note the current version is 7.5.8 released July 23rd 2018.

If you are using a version of Notepad++ older than v6.4.5, the rest of this answer still applies.

### Natively

You can do this natively in Notepad++, but in order to replicate the behaviour of Firefox, you need to disable the document switcher and MRU behaviour.

#### Disable MRU functionality

1. Navigate to ***Settings > Preferences... > MISC.***.

   - Where it says ***Document Switcher (Ctrl+TAB)*** uncheck the first check box **Enable**.
   - Hit the ***Close*** button.

#### Create the Ctrl+PGUP/PGDN shortcuts

1. Navigate to ***Settings > Shortcut Mapper...***.

   - Make sure you are on the ***Main menu*** tab.
   - Scroll to the bottom and you should see in entries 192 ***Switch to previous document*** and 193 ***Switch to next document***.
   - By default these should be mapped to ***Ctrl+Shift+Tab*** and ***Ctrl+Tab*** respectively.
   - Double click anywhere on the 192 line and change it to ***Ctrl+Page up***.
   - Double click anywhere on the 193 line and change it to ***Ctrl+Page down***.
   - Hit the ***Close*** button.

That's it!

Please note that you will no longer have access to the `Ctrl+Tab/Shift+Tab` MRU behaviour now. If, like me, you cannot live without this read on.

### Another (better) option

Notepad++ defaults to using the back and forward buttons on a mouse to switch to the adjacent left and right tabs, so if you are a fan of AutoHotkey, you can use this little script:

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_class Notepad++
; Switch to the adjacent tab to the left
^PgUp::
    Send, {XButton1}
    Return
; Switch to the adjacent tab to the right
^PgDn::
    Send, {XButton2}
    Return
```

This won't interfere with other programs and enables to you have your cake and eat it! You can navigate left and right through adjacent the tabs using `Ctrl+PgUp` and `Ctrl+PgDn` and you can still switch to your last used tab using the built-in document switcher functionality using `Ctrl+Tab` and `Ctrl+Shift+Tab` - just like Firefox :)

Comment: This is just what I've been wanting for a long time.. to be able to use Ctrl+PgDown AND/OR Ctrl+Tab to move to the next Tab (and the complementary inverse)...  
I haven't tried it yet, but I will tomorrow... I'll be using Autoit3 (the parent of AutoHotKey, as I understand.. AutoHotKey forked off from Autoit me-thinks, if my memory is up to par :)

Comment: Wow, where's the +100 button?

Comment: Unfortunately, if holding ctrl and pressing pgup multiple times, the subsequent presses have no effect. This is different from what I'm used to in other apps, eg Firefox.

Comment: Tabbing through multiple tabs using Ctrl + PgUp and PgDown works in version 6.6.9

Comment: I was going to answer with an AutoHotKey script but looks like you beat me to it. :)

Comment: More importantly, how do you make it so that this setting (and others) doesn't revert back to the garbage default after an update?

Answer (score 13):

Settings -> Preferences -> MISC, Document switcher (Ctrl-TAB). Uncheck the "Enable" checkbox. Documents will then be navigated to in the order they appear in the tabs.

You can also assign different keyboard shortcuts to next/previous document if you prefer.

Comment: Disabling the Most Recent Use (MRU) behavior under settings should do what you want.

Answer (score 7):

Using AutoHotkey, if the mouse back and forward buttons are already mapped by the user for a different purpose, lukescammell's solution can be modified to use Browser_Back and Browser_Forward instead:

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_class Notepad++
; Switch to the adjacent tab to the left
^PgUp::
    Send, {Browser_Back}
    Return
; Switch to the adjacent tab to the right
^PgDn::
    Send, {Browser_Forward}
    Return
```

These are extra media buttons found on some multimedia keyboards for going back and forward in a Web browser.

Comment: I was going to answer with an AutoHotKey script but looks like you beat me to it. :)

Answer (score 5):

Nowadays, this is the default behaviour, so if you are able to upgrade to the latest version of Notepad++, you should.

The new shortcuts 141 (Next Tab) and 142 (Previous Tab), which didn't exist until at least version 6.4.3, are now mapped to Ctrl+PgDn and Ctrl+PgUp.

This also circumvents the MRU dialog, so it's a double win.

Answer (score 1):

**Settings > Shortcut Mapper**
[image]

Edit the shortcut and restart:　use Alt + 1/2/3 to switch to Tab 1/2/3

Comment: interesting....

Answer (score -1):

Short answer:

> Ctrl + page up/down