# How can I switch tabs in Notepad++ via Ctrl+PgUp/Down?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, notepad++, tabs

How can I run through the tabs in Notepad++ easily?

I would like to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd>/<kbd>PgDn</kbd> like in Firefox.

Comment: @DavidPostill the linked duplicate is younger than this one

Comment: @Burgi That doesn't matter. It has a better answer. see the edit to the accepted answer to this one: "shoot, this question is answered far better here:

Switching to tabs to the right or left of the current tab in Notepad++

Wish I'd seen that first! :)"

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I'm using Notepad++ version 5.7, and it's simple to change the behavior to do exactly what you're looking for -- use Ctrl+PgUp/PgDown to change tabs just like in Firefox. Here's how:

Step 1:  Click Settings | Shortcut Mapper... and make sure "Main menu" is highlighted at the top of the window. Then scroll to the very bottom of the list, and find the line that says "Switch to previous document". Double click on it's current shortcut value, and in the window that comes up change the shortcut to "Ctrl + Page up". Similarly, change the shortcut for "Switch to next document" to "Ctrl + Page down".

Step 2:  Click Settings | Preferences... | MISC. tab. In the "Document Switcher (Ctrl+TAB)" box, uncheck "Enable MRU behavior". This is needed so that switching to the next/previous document will switch to an adjacent tab, rather than switching to the Most Recently Used tab.

EDIT: shoot, this question is answered far better here:

[Switching to tabs to the right or left of the current tab in Notepad++](https://superuser.com/questions/137230/switching-to-tabs-to-the-right-or-left-of-the-current-tab-in-notepad)

Wish I'd seen that first! :)

Comment: In step 2, you'll want to uncheck "Enable" to disable the document switcher.  This matches what the link above says too.  Anyway, thanks for the info!

Comment: The settings weren't sticking for me after closing notepad++ but I found the solution here: http://ehc.ac/p/notepad-plus/bugs/938/

Comment: that's it ; ) thx ...

Answer (score 16):

Use Ctrl + Tab . Same will apply to most tabbed applications. :)

Comment: And also don't forget to disable "Document Switcher" in preference.

Comment: Ctrl+Tab is smart tab, Ctrl+PgUp/Down is cycling tabs in order.

Answer (score 1):

Use **Cntrl+Shft+Tab** to run through the documents.

From [All the keyboard shortcuts](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/shortcuts.php)

**Ctrl+Tab** switches between 2 documents.

Answer (score 1):

To enable Ctrl+PgUp/Down tab-switching behaviour, **use [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com) script:**

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_class Notepad++
^PgDn::send {XButton2}
^PgUp::send {XButton1}
```

This script has a minor bug: when Notepad++ window is focused but the mouse pointer is placed *outside of it*, then the AutoHotkey `{XButton2}` will go to the window over which the mouse pointer floats. (Has anybody found a better solution?)

This script is based on the one taken from [this blog](http://www.stat.tamu.edu/~aredd/site/?q=node/47).

Answer (score 0):

[image: set shortcut]

Set the shortcut by yourself. my farvourite shortcut is to use `Alt + 1/2/3` to switch to `Tab 1/2/3`

Answer (score 0):

For quick tab switching I could recommend you my free open source plugin 'NavigateTo' - https://github.com/young-developer/nppNavigateTo/releases

This plugin is something like **NavigateTo** in Visual Studio but it is more simple. It allows you to quickly search and navigate between opened files(tabs)

You can open plugin form under the “**Plugins > Navigate To** ” menu in Notepad++ or use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>COMMA</kbd> to bring up the “Navigate To” dialog and then search by filename(path) and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to navigate to opened file.

Comment: Can you explain what your plugin actually does? There is no readme on your github site ...

Comment: @DavidPostill, This plugin is something like NavigateTo in Visual Studio but it is more simple. It allows you to quickly search and navigate between opened files(tabs).

Comment: https://github.com/young-developer/nppNavigateTo/blob/master/README.md

Comment: @OleksiiMaryshchenko - You have multiple identical answers, that all recomend your software, and none of the follow the guidlines to software recomendations here at Supuser.  On top of that, you only need one answer that suggests you tool, flag the other questions as duplicates as the one question you answer.  You should Improve the quality of your answers

Comment: @Ramhound , Done