# How to change control-tab in Notepad++ to web browser style?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, notepad++

How can I make control-tab (and control-shift-tab) behave sensibly in Notepad++? I would like these shortcuts to behave as they do in my web browser, ie. control-tab moves focus to the next tab to the right, control-shift-tab to the tab to the left. Currently they change tab seemingly at random.

Comment: Since asking this question I defected to the editor Sublime Text http://www.sublimetext.com/3

Answer (score 47, accepted):

1. Browse the menu Settings > Preferences > **MISC**.
2. Look for the box **Document Switcher**
3. Uncheck "**Enable**" checkbox (that will untick "**Enable MRU behaviour**" too)

Comment: MRU is Most Recently Used. It switches between the tabs based on which ones were used most recently.

Comment: MRU = Many Regrets Unable, obviously.

Answer (score 3):

[This answer by Luke Scammell](https://superuser.com/questions/137230/switching-to-tabs-to-the-right-or-left-of-the-current-tab-in-notepad#answer-162275) has a very full explanation, as well as instructions for creating your own preferred keyboard shortcuts (I prefer Alt+LeftArrow and Alt+RightArrow).

Note that in the current version of NP++ (6.6.7) the lines to change in ***Settings / Shortcut Mapper*** are lines 219/220 (about 7 up from bottom of list).

Also, Luke includes an autohotkey macro/script that allows you to retain the default NP++ behaviour, but still use your preferred keyboard shortcuts *in addition to* the defaults.