# Is there a way for notepad++ to not remember tab order?

Tags: notepad++

I close a tab and it jumps to some other (Seemingly random) tab (I'm guessing the it is actually the previously selected tab but not 100% on that).

I would prefer it just open the tab to the right of it (like a lot of applications do, e.g. Chrome).

Is there any way to control this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change control-tab in Notepad++ to web browser style?](https://superuser.com/questions/463824/how-to-change-control-tab-in-notepad-to-web-browser-style)

Comment: Try in *Settings > Preferences > MISC.*, under "Document Switcher (Ctrl+TAB)", to uncheck "Enable MRU behaviour".

Comment: @MC10 It isn't exactly like Chrome but good enough and will probably save some hair pulling and cursing. Thanks for the help with this.

Comment: @harrymc Appreciate it, as mentioned I think this is close enough.

Comment: Did the settings change help with the problem?

Comment: @harrymc so far so good, doesn't jump around anymore which is what I wanted to stop.

Comment: I added an answer. Hopefully this is fixed for good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stop Notepad++ from favoring the most-recently-used tab order:

- Run the Notepad++ menu option *Settings > Preferences...*
- Position to the *MISC.* section
- Under "Document Switcher (Ctrl+TAB)", uncheck "Enable MRU behaviour"
- Click OK.